# CORS issue while shaping working web app into a native Ionic app for Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, cors, capacitor

I've been trying to set up this **Ionic CLI proxy server** following this [guide](https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/), but it's from 2015 and I have no idea how to implement it in Angular 10.

So when I run my app with a command:

```
ionic capacitor run android --project=myApp -c=production
```

I have this error in Android Studio:

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/login - Line 0 - Msg: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://remoteServer.com/api/v1/oauth/v2/token' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' head
```

This is my **capacitor.config.json** file:

```
{
  "appId": "io.ionic.starter",
  "appName": "myApp",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {},
  "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
}
```

And this is my **ionic.config.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://remoteServer.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.18.3 (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.6
   OS     : Linux 5.4
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? I've been searching for ages...

---

edit:

So I followed Angular's instructions on [how to make an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) and this article that explains [how to implement both HttpClient and Ionic's native HTTP](https://manuel-heidrich.dev/blog/an-elegant-way-to-handle-native-http-requests-with-cordova-advanced-http-in-an-ionic-app/), but I run into new issues.

Using the code from article, TS is complaining about this line:

`headers: nativeHttpResponse.headers`

```
(property) headers?: HttpHeaders
Type '{ [key: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpHeaders': headers, normalizedNames, lazyInit, lazyUpdate, and 12 more.ts(2740)
http.d.ts(3406, 9): The expected type comes from property 'headers' which is declared here on type '{ body?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; }'
```

Here's the whole native-http.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";
import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";

type HttpMethod =
  | "get"
  | "post"
  | "put"
  | "patch"
  | "head"
  | "delete"
  | "upload"
  | "download";

@Injectable()
export class NativeHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private nativeHttp: HTTP, private platform: Platform) {}

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return from(this.handleNativeRequest(request));
  }

  private async handleNativeRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<any>
  ): Promise<HttpResponse<any>> {
    const headerKeys = request.headers.keys();
    const headers = {};

    headerKeys.forEach((key) => {
      headers[key] = request.headers.get(key);
    });

    try {
      await this.platform.ready();

      const method = <HttpMethod>request.method.toLowerCase();

      // console.log(‘— Request url’);
      // console.log(request.url)
      // console.log(‘— Request body’);
      // console.log(request.body);

      const nativeHttpResponse = await this.nativeHttp.sendRequest(
        request.url,
        {
          method: method,
          data: request.body,
          headers: headers,
          serializer: "json",
        }
      );

      let body;

      try {
        body = JSON.parse(nativeHttpResponse.data);
      } catch (error) {
        body = { response: nativeHttpResponse.data };
      }

      const response = new HttpResponse({
        body: body,
        status: nativeHttpResponse.status,
        headers: nativeHttpResponse.headers,  <--------
        url: nativeHttpResponse.url,
      });

      // console.log(‘— Response success’)
      // console.log(response);

      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } catch (error) {
      if (!error.status) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      const response = new HttpResponse({
        body: JSON.parse(error.error),
        status: error.status,
        headers: error.headers,
        url: error.url,
      });

      return Promise.reject(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how my `app.module.ts` looks like:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    IonicModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [HTTP],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Andd here is how my `core.module.ts` (where I want to use interceptor) looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { NativeHttpInterceptor } from "./service/native-http.interceptor";
import { AuthService } from "./service/auth.service";
import { ApiService } from "./service/api.service";
import { AuthGuardService } from "./service/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthInterceptor } from "./service/auth-interceptor";
import { WindowRef } from "./service/window-ref-service";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NativeHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthService,
    ApiService,
    AuthGuardService,
    WindowRef,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the Server to apply some configs?

Comment: Here is the updated Ionic article for CORS: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors

Comment: @yazantahhan no, I don't have permissions to change anything on BE

Thanks for the link.

Comment: Can you put the block of code that is complaining about the header?

Comment: @yazantahhan TS error added + native-http.interceptor.ts & app.module.ts & core.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy configs will only work for the `ionic serve` or the `livereload` of the native builds.

If you can't change any option in the BE, then the easiest way is to use a native plugin for the HTTP requests [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http) which will send the requests without the origin header (As it is not sent from the browser).

You can use the Ionic Native wrapper for this from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http).

Comment: Do you happen to know if and how can I relatively easily replace my HttpClient with this HTTP plugin? I have hundreds of lines of code in api.service that I'd have to modify...

Comment: You can have an interceptor that will do this for you. Create an [HTTP interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) that will capture all requests and responses, then you will use the plugin to send the request instead of the HttpClient. It will need some work but this is the best approach so you don't have to change all other places. All of your logic will be in one place

Comment: You can check this: https://manuel-heidrich.dev/blog/an-elegant-way-to-handle-native-http-requests-with-cordova-advanced-http-in-an-ionic-app/

Comment: Is there an example project with this implementation out there? I can't make it work...

Comment: TS is complaining about "headers" type on this line: 
        headers: nativeHttpResponse.headers

Comment: I'll just create a new stack-overflow question as this one got the original error solved.